# Problems with adding NetLogo extension for Mac

Tags: matlab, netlogo

I'm having a problem adding the matlab-extension folder previously developed (https://github.com/mbi2gs/netlogo-matlab-extension/wiki) into the net logo extension folder. I think there is some problem with my ability to write into the NetLogo folders. I have tried troubleshooting with erasing and rewriting the drive, and by checking the 'ignore ownership on this volume' in the get info box. But neither of these have helped adding files into NetLogo. My system is macOS Sierra v. 10.12.6 and NetLogo 6.1.1.

[image: NetLogo GetInfo]

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I don't have MatLab installed, but here are a few things you could try.

It looks like you are running NetLogo from inside the disk image (dmg file) it came in.  This might work, but generally I'd advise copying the `NetLogo 6.1.1` folder out of the disk image into your `Applications` folder and getting rid of the disk image entirely.  You can either open the the NetLogo disk image and the `Applications` folder at the same time then drag the `NetLogo 6.1.1` folder over, or you can select the `NetLogo 6.1.1` folder and Command-C to copy then Command-V to paste the folder to the Applications.

The second step is to make you sure you have the `matlab` folder copied into the `extensions` folder under the `NetLogo 6.1.1` folder, per those MatLab extension directions.

If the Matlab extension does write to the NetLogo folder while it's running, you may have to repeat those steps you tried to give your user read and write access to the `NetLogo 6.1.1` folder, too.

Here is a pic of how things look with my `NetLogo 6.1.1` folder in the `Applications` folder and the `matlab` extension copied in.

[image: NetLogo 6.1.1 folder contents]

If none of that helps, one alternative to try is to place the contents of the `matlab` extension folder in a new folder inside your `Documents` folder, something like `matlab-models`.   Then if you place an `nlogo` model file there and load it, NetLogo should use this `matlab-models` folder's copy of the extension, and you'll definitely have proper permission to write to it in your `Documents` folder.  You want the `matlab.jar` file right alongside the `nlogo` models you use Matlab with if you try this.